# Do DataContext assign on XAML pointing to its code behind class

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 application with a User Control.

On this user control, I want to do the datacontext on XAML pointing to its codebehind. Now I'm doing it on the constructor:

```
public CustomOptionButton()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

But, **How can I do it on XAML?**

Comment: If you are trying a create a reusable component I would not user a UserControl, I would suggest creating a custom control. That way you can use TemplateBinding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<UserControl Name="LayoutRoot" 
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ... />
```

or:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:TestViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

or:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MyViewModel x:Key="TestViewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource TestViewModel}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 1):

when i'm using current datacontext in my custom controls, this is what i am doing:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
d:DataContext="{Binding}"
```

**EDIT**

As @WiredPrairie pointed out i misunderstood the question, so this is more easy way and aleternative to what @AnatoliyNikolaev suggest

```
x:Name="_this">  
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}">
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing as what was asked. It would just bind to the already established `DataContext` from the parent control. The question was about binding to the control itself.